# Как ввести число и столько же раз можно было ввести имён и потом их вывести?

Tags: java, for

напишите простую программу, которая:

запрашивает количество незнакомцев, с которыми нужно встретиться
построчно читает имена незнакомцев
построчно выводит: "Hello, (имя незнакомца)" для каждого незнакомца.
Гарантируется, что введенное количество незнакомцев — целое число.

Частные случаи:
Если количество незнакомцев равно нулю, программа должна вывести: "Oh, it looks like there is no one here".
Если количество незнакомцев отрицательное, программа должна вывести: "Seriously? Why so negative?".

Как реализовать, чтоб ввести число и столько же раз можно было ввести имён и потом их вывести?

```
public class HelloStrangers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan  = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = scan.nextInt();

               if (amount<0) {
            System.out.println("Seriously? Why so negative?");
        }
        if (amount==0) {
            System.out.println("Oh, it looks like there is no one here");
        }
        else (amount> 0) {
    String input  = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: поробуйте решить задачу сасостоятельно, а если возникнуть вопросы - задавайте

Comment: я обозначила проблему, которая мне не дается

Comment: вы про циклы что-то слышали? если нет, то вот сейчас самое время))

Comment: слышали и даже читали и знает. но здесь-просто ступор

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, что такое "ступор" в контексте использования цикла , который итерируется n-ое количество раз (что является его прямым назначением), но ладно, будем бороться со ступором:

```
public class HelloStrangers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = Integer.valueOf(sanner.nextLine());
        if (amount < 0) {
            System.out.println("Seriously? Why so negative?");
        } else if (amount == 0) {
            System.out.println("Oh, it looks like there is no one here");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) System.out.println("Hello, " + sanner.nextLine());
        }
    }    
}
```

Если есть вопросы, смело задавайте

Comment: Ступор- это когда еще недостаточно опыта  не знаешь возможно прямо все методы, а задачу уже надо решить, а идей-просто нет, так как все, что пробовал-не работает)))и гугл не помогает)) не судите строго, я только учусь) Надеюсь потом буду смеяться, что не могла найти решение )

Comment: @Sviatlana Yezhaleva так никто же не судит, вон даже с решением помогаю)) просто это прямой намек на решение: "попробуйте использовать циклы") и в итоге я именно цикл и использовал, никаких неожиданностей и код от вашего кардинальных отличий не имеет. но раз ступор все равно спрошу: вы с решением разобрались или все еще непонятно как это работает?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю это поможет другим участникам, кто учит Java, когда совсем сдался. Я в начале этого пути) Удачи мне и вам, ребята!

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer x = scanner.nextInt();
        if (x < 0) {
            System.out.println("Серьезно? А что так негативно?");
        } else if (x == 0) {
            System.out.println("Оу... Похоже здесь никого...");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                String str = scanner.next();
                System.out.println("Привет, " + str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Это весь код для решения задачи.